# change binding created by v-model in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Stackoverflowers, I'm a newbie of vue.js, I try to implement a binding effect which can enable the changing of binding created by `v-model`. To put things clear, I give an example as following:

```html
<codemirror ref="outputCm" v-model="output" :options="cmOutputOptions"></codemirror>
```

Here we have a codemirror element, it's content is binded with variable `output`, is it possible in some place after I changed `output` to `some-variable`, its content now is binded with `some-variable`? I tried to use assignment, it didn't work. And I tried my best to google, but I'm still disappointed. If anybody know how to give this a shot, I'm appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by rebinding the model? It sounds like you've picked a solution without examining the real problem.

Comment: I just want to reuse this codemirror to hold json output or plain text (some logs), either has updates, the content of codemirror just sync with it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you could make it but from your data object

```
data: {
    output: (your logic here)? some-variable : 'some thing else'
}
```

Comment: Hi, Joseph, I give your method a try, it didn't work as expected. In data object, I make output as `output: this.showLogs ? this.log : this.jsonOutput`, but nothing outputs